# Autofac.Extensions.Hosting NuGet?

Tags: autofac

Does anyone know how to install **Autofac.Extensions.Hosting** from a NuGet package within Visual Studio (2019)?  I see the project here [GitHub Autofac.Extensions.Hosting](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.Hosting).  Within the project instructions, it states that you can "reference the  from NuGet".  However, I can't find it within Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager.  Is it not available yet, or am I doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was never published because it's basically just one extension method. The readme needs to be corrected. If you need the extension method, just copy paste it.